# SQL Week over Week query for given timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table that is used for support tickets. I am trying to create a query that shows a week over week breakdown (how many tickets were created) for the last 8 weeks.

I have a calendar table created already and I am trying to make use of this to create the query.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Calendar
WHERE calendar_DT >= DATEADD(week, -8, GETUTCDATE() -1)
AND calendar_DT <= GETUTCDATE()
ORDER BY calendar_DT ASC
```

[image]

Here I have a basic query that gives me all of the dates within the last 8 weeks. From here, I am trying to group this data by week so that I have a `weekStart`, `weekEnd` and then a count of records created which I will join another table for.

I attempted to do this without a calendar table but it seems that if records didn't exist for a specific week then theres gaps in the results instead of a `0`.

This was my original attempt. Its close to what I want for the end result. However, I am not sure where the `null` is coming from and its missing a 2 weeks of data where no requests were created during this time.

```
SELECT  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdDate), 0) [From],
        DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdDate), 0) + 6 [To],
        COUNT(DISTINCT reqID) newRequests
FROM dbo.support_tickets
WHERE createdDate >= DATEADD(week, -8, GETUTCDATE())
AND tool = 244
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdDate) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdDate)
```

[image]

Desired result looks like the image above, a total count of records created for each of the last 8 weeks.

Do I need to continue with the use of the calendar table or can it be done without it and still show the `to/from` even if theres no results for that week?

Comment: The point of the calendar table is that is the base of your query. If you exclude that how do you propose you would return a row from your query when there is no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NULL row is the result of your GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP. That's the rollup. The newRequests value of 7 is the total of your other records.

If you want dates to be listed that aren't in your table, you'll need to get them from somewhere else, which is just what a calendar table is for. So you're actually in pretty good shape once you add that join.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I think thats what I need to try and figure out, joining the calendar table and grouping it by week

Comment: There are probably at least a half dozen ways to manage that. One way might be to join your createdDate to the Calendar_DT, group by week_ending_date, and just calculate week start date. With no table schemas, I'm not sure that'd work, but something along those lines.